# Выдаёт ошибку create_cookie() got unexpected keyword arguments: ['id', 'hostOnly', 'httpOnly', 'storeId', 'sameSite', 'expirationDate', 'session']

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, cookie

При запуске программы выдаёт create_cookie() got unexpected keyword arguments: ['id', 'hostOnly', 'httpOnly', 'storeId', 'sameSite', 'expirationDate', 'session']
Насколько я понимаю, эти значения cookie нестандартные из-за этого выдаёт ошибку

Код:

```
import requests

url = 'https://playerok.com/wallet/withdraw'

headers = {
"Accept": "*/*",
"User-Agent": "user-agent"
    }

cookies_dict = [
{
    "domain": ".playerok.com",
    "expirationDate": 1698540269.814604,
    "hostOnly": False,
    "httpOnly": True,
    "name": "__cf_bm",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "secure": True,
    "session": False,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "value",
    "id": 1
}
]

#Создание сессии
session_1 = requests.Session()

for cookie in cookies_dict:
    session_1.cookies.set(**cookie)

response = session_1.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```